# Google Charts - Cannot get column chart to format

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Ugh, the documentation for this seems so blasted clear, but I can't seem to correctly change the colors of the bars in my chart. There has to be something obvious that I'm missing....here's what I'm working with at the moment:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>

       <div id="dual_y_div" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>
         
<script>
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
    function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ["Companies", "Acres", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 700,
          height: 500,
          chart: {
            title: 'Haynesville / Bossier Play - Sample Acreage Estimates',
            subtitle: 'updated December 15, 2015'
          },
          series: {
            0: { axis: 'Acres' }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'distance'.           
          },
          axes: {
            y: {
              Acres: {label: 'Acres'}, // Left y-axis.            
            }
          }
        };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
</script>
```

In my mind, I've defined the role, and formatted the colors exactly as they're shown on the docs - and yet I still have all blue (default) bar colorings.

[![Screenshot of Blue Bars][1]][1]

So, yeah, there's that. What did I botch?

As always, SO community, thanks for your time, attention, and expertise.

CDM

Update:

So now I'm here, but still with blue bars:

```js
function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ["Companies", "Acres", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Conoco", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Tesla", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Texaco", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Yahoo.com", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 700,
          chart: {
            title: 'Haynesville / Bossier Play - Sample Acreage Estimates',
            subtitle: 'updated December 15, 2015'
          },
          series: {
            0: { axis: 'Acres' }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'Acres'.           
          },
          axes: {
            y: {
              Acres: {label: 'Acres'}, // Left y-axis.            
            }
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted in your question works fine with a few simple changes:

In this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
```

Change `'packages':['bar']` to 'packages':['corechart']

And in this line:

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div'));
```

Change `google.charts.Bar` to `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

And change this options code:

```
var options = {
  width: 700,
  chart: {
    title: 'Haynesville / Bossier Play - Sample Acreage Estimates',
    subtitle: 'updated December 15, 2015'
  },
  series: {
    0: { axis: 'Acres' }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'Acres'.           
  },
  axes: {
    y: {
      Acres: {label: 'Acres'}, // Left y-axis.            
    }
  }
};
```

To this instead:

```
var options = {
  title: 'Haynesville / Bossier Play - Sample Acreage Estimates',
  legend: {
    position: 'none'
  },
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Companies'
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Acres'
  }
};
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44p8srt6/1/)

Note that the regular Google charts do not support subtitles, so that is why I left the subtitle out in the options code I posted above.

Google *material* charts **do** support subtitles, but they apply colors to each *series* of data in your chart, not to each value within a series. Here's the complete code to use the *material* chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>

<div id="dual_y_div" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>

<script>
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ["Companies", "Acres1", "Acres2", "Acres3", "Acres4"],
      ["Conoco", 8.94, 10.21, 5.67, 14.53],
      ["Tesla", 10.49, 16.32, 20.15, 13.49],
      ["Texaco", 19.30, 17.10, 15.23, 25.37],
      ["Yahoo.com", 21.45, 22.32, 18.19, 27.43]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Haynesville / Bossier Play - Sample Acreage Estimates',
        subtitle: 'updated December 15, 2015'
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      colors: ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2'],
      series: {
        0: { axis: 'Acres' },
        1: { axis: 'Acres' },
        2: { axis: 'Acres' },
        3: { axis: 'Acres' }
      },
      axes: {
        y: {
          Acres: {label: 'Acres'}, // Left y-axis.            
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
  };
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44p8srt6/2/)

I have not found a way to change the color shown on the material chart for each value within a series. So, it looks like you have to make a choice between omitting the subtitle and having the chart colors the way you want, or including the subtitle by using the material chart but having the color for each value within a series be the same.

Comment: Any idea why I can't see the Title / Subtitle of the Chart?

Comment: Amended my answer to get your title and axis labels working

Answer (score 0):

This how u change the color of graph

```
var options = {
            colors: ['#2980b9']
        };
```

add this `color` option in ur `options` variable

in your case

```
var options = {
      width: 700,
      colors: ['#2980b9'],
      .....
      .....
```

if you have two bars in ur chart den do like this `colors: ['#0d6957','#1fb89a']`

Comment: thanks for the tip. So since I have four columns in the current table, would my formatting look like this:

colors: ['#2980b9', '#0431B4; '#DF013A', '#F7FE2E'],

Comment: can u add jsfiddel  i will fix into that

Comment: Thanks for the help sir!